# Example for universal sentence that is true in substructure but not in structure

Tags: logic

I'm looking for an example for structures $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{A'}$ and a universal sentence $\Phi$ such that

$\mathcal{A} \models \Phi$ but  $\mathcal{A'} \not\models \Phi$ (in first-order logic).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $A$ be a one-element structure, and let the sentence be $\forall x\forall y(x=y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Pick the language $\{c\}$ with $c$ being some constant symbol. Now consider $\forall x(x=c)$. And a structure with more than one element, what would be the substructure here? Can you find a way to make this into a statement in the language with only equality?